# Block sites with invalid SSL certificate in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Is it possible to configure Internet Explorer (version 9 or 10) to completely block sites without valid SSL certificate?

Comment: This actually should be the default behavior.  What security level is IE set to?

Comment: Default behavior is a warning, which may be skipped. I want full blocking.

Comment: In order to block the website, the certificate can't exist in the Certificate Store, you didn't answer my question about the security level.

Comment: basically medium-high security settings. But I cannot see there any option related to blocking sites without valid ssl certificate.